# Can a text node be slotted?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Is it possible to assign a text node to a slot when using `<template>` and `<slot>`s?

Say I have a template that looks like

```
<template>
  <span>
    <slot name="mySlot"></slot>
  </span>
</template>
```

I would like to be able to add only text to the slot, instead of having to add a `<span>` open and close tag each time I use the template. Is this possible? If not in pure HTML, in JavaScript?

It is also better to pass in the text content only so that no styling is applied on the way in. Currently I'm using an invalid tag `<n>` to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can with **imperative slot assignment**, but not yet in Safari.

- You **can not** slot a text node into a *named slot* (declarative).
- Mixing declarative and imperative slots is **not** possible.
- `::slotted(*)` can **not** target text nodes.

---

- https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/blob/gh-pages/proposals/Imperative-Shadow-DOM-Distribution-API.md
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_shadowroot_slotassignment
  [image]

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("slotted-textnodes", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({
        mode: 'open',
        slotAssignment: 'manual' // imperative assign only
      }).innerHTML = `<style>::slotted(*){color:red}</style>
                      Click me! <slot name="title"></slot> <slot>NONE</slot>!!!`;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let nodes = [], node;
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till lightDOM is parsed
        const nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
          this, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
            acceptNode: (node) => node.parentNode == this && (/\S/.test(node.data))
          }
        );
        while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) nodes.push(node);
        this.onclick = (e) => {
          this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot:not([name])").assign(nodes[0]);
          nodes.push(nodes.shift());
        }
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<slotted-textnodes>
  Foo
  <hr separator>Bar<hr separator>
  <b>text INSIDE nodes ignored by iterator filter!</b>
  Baz
  <span slot="title">Can't mix Declarative and Imperative slots!!!</span>
</slotted-textnodes>
```

Comment: The code looks quite complicated for this straight forward task, but from what I can understand you are showing me text nodes can be inserted into unnamed slots?

Comment: Yes, any Node can be assigned to any ``<slot>``, but it is either this _imperative_ approach, **or** the _declarative_ approach with **named** slots.. and you can only name HTMLElements, not textNodes

Comment: Can only be done with the imperative method, in a slotchange event