# Web Components - Multiple elements per slot

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, slots

I'm working on new web-components and ran into some issues concerning slots.

I have an outer container-component with a "main-slot" inside, in which **multiple** elements should be inserted (into the same slot). However, it is only possible to add one element per named slot.

My question: is there a way to add multiple elements to one named slot? Like shown here:

```
<own-container>
   <own-element slot="main"></own-element>
   <own-element slot="main"></own-element>
   <own-element slot="main"></own-element>
   <own-element slot="main"></own-element>
</own-container>
```

Comment: see addendum to my answer; you can have multiple elements in one slot; so there must be something else wrong with your code. Use the [<>] button in the StackOverflow editor and show us running (but failing) code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also [imperative <slot>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706107/can-a-text-node-be-slotted)

```js
super().attachShadow({
        mode: 'open',
        slotAssignment: 'manual' // imperative assign only
      })
```

**But! you get *Named* slots OR *Imperative* slots, on one Web Component**

To mimic *named* `<slot>`, assigning content to the same named `<slot>`
you probably need the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

### addendum

You can have multiple elements per slot:

```html
<component-with-slots>
    <H1 slot="title">Web Components are great!</H1>
    <h2 slot="title">A bit hard to master</h2>
    <b slot="title">But Great!</b>
</component-with-slots>

<script>
  customElements.define('component-with-slots', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() { 
        super()
          .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
          .innerHTML = `<slot name="title"></slot>`; 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is a bit verbose (of course due to the fact of being **imperative**) but looks clean.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. It is not possible for named slot. The trick is to have a wrapper `div` element to wrap your `lightDOM`.

```html
<own-container>
  <div slot="main">
    <own-element></own-element>
    <own-element></own-element>
    <own-element></own-element>
    <own-element></own-element>
  </div>
</own-container>
```

If the presence of additional `div` causes styling problem, then you can use new `contents` type of display box.

```css
div {
  display: contents;
}
```

The [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself. However, note that it can cause **accessibility** issues.

Comment: Nice solution! You can even put the styling burden on the slot-container with `slot[name=main]::slotted(*) { display: contents; }`.